# Is there any way to see which applications are the most downloaded from the Software Center?

Tags: software-center

Being quite used to the Android market I've always found it quite interesting to be able to see the statistics on how many times an application has been downloaded:

[image]

With the Ubuntu Software Center it seems that the only information available to sort application by is the date they were uploaded and their rating:

[image]

Is there any way of seeing how many times an application has been downloaded from the Software Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [back in 2005](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter) 'most downloaded' was suppose to be part of USC but I doubt it will ever be added again.

Anyone that installed the `popularity-contest` package does get their downloads shown on the [Ubuntu Popularity Contest](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/) website.

Example from the website:

- [packages from `main`](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/main/by_inst)
- [packages from `restricted`](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/restricted/by_inst)
- [packages from `main`, `games`](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/main/games/by_inst)

Comment: That's a shame, though having had more of a search I've come across [Top 10 Ubuntu app downloads for March 2012](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/top-10-ubuntu-app-downloads-for-march-2012/) so presumably Canonical do have statistics for the Software Center but they just don't want to share :(

Comment: "The lists of top 10 app downloads includes only those applications submitted through My Apps on the Ubuntu App Developer Site." ;)